# download file after perl post

Tags: perl, http

This request returns a file of type ZIP how can I retrieve that file from that request?

```
# put timeouts, proxy etc into the useragent if needed
my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $req = POST $in_u, Content_Type => 'form-data', Content => $in_r;

my $response = $ua->request($req);

if ($response->is_success()) 
{
    print $response->content;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the content method on your $req object to get the raw content returned as a result of the POST. If the content is huge, then content_ref method is more suitable and offers to directly manipulate the content.

```
my $zfile = $req->content;
```

and crack on $zfile with Archive::Zip as DVK suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Archive::Zip` CPAN module